# Mac OS X keeps to ask me if I want to allow iTunes to accept connections

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, itunes

Every time I open iTunes, Mac OS X keeps to ask me if I want to allow it to accept connections, even if in the Firewall settings iTunes has been set to accept any connections.

I am not using a beta version of iTunes.

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: I've noticed this each time I open iTunes too, it's strange as normally there's an option to allow always.

Comment: @LC1983: That is the option I selected, but still I am asked if I want to allow iTunes to accept connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's unusual because applications created by Apple should be automatically permitted access through the firewall.  Have you modified iTunes (added plugins for example) in any way?  You can check if iTunes' digital signature is valid with the following Terminal command:

`codesign -vvv /Applications/iTunes.app/`

You should get two lines back looking like those in the image below

[image: Terminal output]

If these don't match with what I have or even if they do, a reinstall of iTunes or removal of any plugins should fix it.

Use the following steps:

1. Uninstall iTunes.
2. Empty Trash.
3. Restart the Mac.
4. Reinstall iTunes

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I keep to get the error message "a sealed resource is missing or invalid", even after re-installing iTunes.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: same problem here, including the 'sealed resource is missing message...'

Comment: It worked for me too, after I removed the iTunes files with an application, even without to restart the Mac.

Comment: I added the 4 steps to the end of the answer which I had provided in the comments.  You may not need to restart but it's sometimes prudent to restart anyway.